# Fatal error:Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in php

Tags: php

I am sending data from controller to mode,

I got below result, I was trying to display the data in grid view.

```
stdClass Object
(
[Tmchb] => stdClass Object
    (
        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Matnr] => 1006-1
                        [J3asize] => S
                        [Maktx] => STOCKHOLM-BLANC
                        [Clabs] => 42.0
                        [Incweek] => 
                        [Zincmgstk] => 0.0
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Matnr] => 1006-10
                        [J3asize] => XXL
                        [Maktx] => STOCKHOLM-ROUGE
                        [Clabs] => 85.0
                        [Incweek] => 
                        [Zincmgstk] => 0.0
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Matnr] => 1006-10
                        [J3asize] => XL
                        [Maktx] => STOCKHOLM-ROUGE
                        [Clabs] => 66.0
                        [Incweek] => 
                        [Zincmgstk] => 0.0
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Matnr] => 1006-10
                        [J3asize] => S
                        [Maktx] => STOCKHOLM-ROUGE
                        [Clabs] => 58.0
                        [Incweek] => 
                        [Zincmgstk] => 0.0
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Matnr] => 1006-10
                        [J3asize] => M
                        [Maktx] => STOCKHOLM-ROUGE
                        [Clabs] => 167.0
                        [Incweek] => 
                        [Zincmgstk] => 0.0
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Matnr] => 1006-10
                        [J3asize] => L
                        [Maktx] => STOCKHOLM-ROUGE
                        [Clabs] => 230.0
                        [Incweek] => 
                        [Zincmgstk] => 0.0
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

But I got error like this.

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in `C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\components\com_portal\views\portal\tmpl\default_stock_details_list.php` on line 139
```

`$grid->CellData =$gridData[0];`

This is my PHP code.

```
function JTPlatinumGrid1RowData($sender, $params) {
$rows = &$params[ 1 ];
$rowdata=$rows;
$alignArray1=array();
    foreach($rowdata as $key=>$val){
        $alignArray1[]=$key;
    }

        for($i=1; $i<=count($alignArray1); $i++){

        if($rows[$alignArray1[$i]]!= ''){
        $rows[$alignArray1[$i]] = '<div style="text-align:right;">' . $rows[$alignArray1[$i]]  . '  </div>';
        }
    }

}
```

what i need to do..

Comment: be more descriptive, Where you using `JTPlatinumGrid1RowData()`? What is the value of `$gridData[0]`? which variable contains that objects array data?

Answer (score 0):

This error means you're trying to access an object field as it was an array. That will never work.

for accessing object fields

```
$object->field_name
```

for accessing array fields

```
$array[field_name]
```

Maybe you'll find useful cast your object to array

```
$array_var = (array) $object_var;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the wrong way.
Say, **$result** has the entire **stdClass object**, then the following code segment should print the elements correctly.

```
foreach ($result->Tmchb->item as $row) {
  print $row->Matnr . " " . $row->J3asize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but as per your need you can try this

```
foreach($grid->CellData->$gridData as row){
  echo row['your value'];
}
```